Can somebody help me understand this video?
Estoy viendo este video corte en español y creo que entiendo la esencia de ello, pero hay algunas partes que todavia me confunden. Especificamente, cuando el chico dice "pues, sí que sí" "pero, que? Bueno, oye" y "verás cielo" que quiere decir? Como se traducirían esas frases?
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uP2Uesi_nVk

Si activa los subtítulos, podrá leer lo que se dice exactamente.

estoy asistiendo a este video.

A better transcription by you here would help.

All of them are colloquial expressions, so you can translate them this way:
pues, sí que sí < > well, yes indeed

pero, que? Bueno, oye < > wait what? oh okay (he realizes that she is trying to make him jealous)
verás cielo < > you see honey


Lo has entendido mal.
Primero dice: "pues sí que es guapo, sí". Reafirmando que es guapo, como ella dice.
Después dice: "Pero, qué bueno, oye". El sentido es "Qué bien que te quiera enseñar muay thai".
Por último: "verás cielo" es como decir: verás = deja que te explique y verás/entenderás. cielo = cariño.

Yo creo que la segunda es: ‘Pero qué? Bueno, oye!’. La pregunta no es una pregunta propiamente dicha, sino una incredulidad del tipo, a la que se autorresponde con ‘bueno, oye’, en parte para descargar la sorpresa y en parte para advertir a la mujer de que en lo que se metió es un ‘buen negocio’
